# what's the best way to determine css pixel ratio for screen sizes, if it isn't listed?

Tags: css, pixel, screen-resolution

what's the best way to determine css pixel ratio for screen sizes, if it isn't listed?
Perhaps, you have these data: width = 480px, height = 800px, physical size = 4.3, ppi = 217.
Is this obvious that css pixel ratio would be 1.5? If it's obvious, is there an article, which best summarizes how css pixel ratio is derived? or relationships between ppi to physical size with display resolution?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

There are usually listings for various mobile devices and tablets that will include screen dimensions, but also pixel ratios.

http://the-chronicon.blogspot.com/2015/01/mobile-device-screen-dimensions-and.html

Also, Chrome has a built in mobile testing evnvironment which lists this information as well for many devices. Just hit F12 in your browser and click on the little phone icon on the top left. From here you can select from a myriad of devices and the specs will be denoted as well. Hope this helps...